# Slicing array returns strange shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, slice, reshape

Suppose I do the following in Ipython:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.zeros([3,2])
test
test.shape
test[:,0]
test[:,0].shape
```

The results will be:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
(3,2)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
(3,)
```

Why is the last result here not `(3,1)`? I have a work-around: The `reshape` command, but that seems silly.

Comment: Use slice to keep the dimension. `test[:,:1]`.

Comment: That returns a shape of (3,1). But if I want a different column, and try `test[:,:0]` I get a shape of (3,0).

Comment: Which column do you want? To get the ith column, `test[:,i:i+1]`.

Comment: NumPy is not a matrix library. It is an n-dimensional array library. `test[:, 0]` is a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: In MATLAB indexing a (n)d matrix like this reduces the dimension to (n-1)d, for n>2.  `numpy` does the same except it doesn't have that artificial 2 minimum dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a different array for visualization:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
>>> test
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

Slicing like this:

```
>>> test[:,0]
array([0, 2, 4])
```

tells NumPy to keep the first dimension but only take the first element of the second dimension. By definition this will reduce the number of dimensions by 1.

Just like:

```
>>> test[0, 0]
0
```

would take the first element in the first dimension and the first element of the second dimension. Thus reducing the number of dimensions by 2.

In case you wanted to get the first column as actual column (not changing the number of dimensions) you need to use slicing:

```
>>> test[:, 0:1]  # remember that the stop is exlusive so this will get the first column only
array([[0],
       [2],
       [4]])
```

or similarly

```
>>> test[:, 1:2]  # for the second column
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])

>>> test[0:1, :]  # first row
array([[0, 1]])
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one coordinate in a given dimension but want to keep that dimension, wrap it in an `array` or `list`

```
test[:,[0]].shape
Out: (3, 1)
```